# Could not load assembly 'System.Buffers' during startup registration

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

My Xamarin form apps was running like 5 minutes ago then all of sudden it stop working. The apps close instantly after it started. 
Below shows message display at Visual studio output,

```
Assembly Loader probing location: 'System.Buffers'.
Could not load assembly 'System.Buffers' during startup registration.
This might be due to an invalid debug installation.
 A common cause is to 'adb install' the app directly instead of doing from the IDE.
```

Things that I tried but failed to resolve the problem,

1. Reinstall System.Buffer from Nuget package.
2. Clean bin and obj folder of android
3. Unchecked use shared runtime at Android options
4. Clean solution and rebuild solution

Forum that I referred

1. https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/115983/stuck-on-error-could-not-load-assembly-system-buffers-during-startup-registration
2. https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/63584/android-could-not-load-assembly-xxx-during-startup-registration
3. https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=44518

Can anyone helps me? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the solution from one of the [forum](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/113718/android-error-with-signalr-core-could-not-load-assembly-system-memory-during-startup-registration).

Uninstall `System.Buffer` and install `System.Memory` using NuGet package to your project and its done. Hope it helps you.

Comment: *Unable to uninstall `System.Buffers.4.4.0` because `System.Memory.4.5.3` depends on it.*

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this issue in little bit different manner. I have installed `System.Memory` from NuGet package manager without uninstalling `System.Buffer`. Then only error is gone. If I am uninstalling `System.Buffer` I still face the same issue.