# Project will not deploy with Xamarin 9

Tags: xamarin.android

My old(ish) Xamarin project compiled and deployed correctly about 12 months ago. Today I have tried recompiling but am having problems. Xamarin has been automatically updated to ver 9.1.7.0: this caused a few references to be wrong but I have corrected those and the project now compiles correctly.

But it will not deploy. Using the emulator I get the following:

*F/monodroid-assembly(22297): Could not load assembly 'System.Configuration' during startup registration*.

Trying to deploy to a real phone, there are no error messages. In both cases a new window opens, with the correct title, but it is blank. In the debugger, the code never reaches the first line breakpoint I have added (in 'OnCreate()')
I Have looked [here](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/63584/android-could-not-load-assembly-xxx-during-startup-registration) and other similar search results e.g.  [here on s.o.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49297409/could-not-load-assembly-system-buffers-during-startup-registration)but none have solved this.

Comment: First of all, after you update the nuget packages, please close your VS, open the application folder, delete `bin` and `obj` folders. rebuild it, then deply it to the emulator. And please dont forget to set the Target Framework to the Android 9.0(Pie) in the Application tab.

Comment: Does this gives you any kind of exception (in the Physical Device) after a few time? also try what Leon Lu said, your project might need some cleanup first

Comment: @LeonLu-MSFT Yes, thanks, I have done the cleanup suggested, (was suggsted elsewhere) , no improvement. Why Android 9? The project  has worked fine in 4.4 for years. My devices are only Android 8 anyway. I have tried compiling for 8., same result.

Comment: @RicardoDiasMorais, no exception in the device.

Comment: you can try and see if there's really an exception going on (but not trowing any error) using this, put this in your MainActivity and see if you catch something (if not readable, i can make an awnser format and delete it afterwards):         private void HandleExceptions(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
        {
            //Handle Exceptions 
            Console.Write(e.ToString());
        }

Comment: and in your OnCreate: AppDomain currentDomain = AppDomain.CurrentDomain;
            currentDomain.UnhandledException += HandleExceptions;

Comment: I added the exception hanler, but no help; as I said eariler the debugger never even reaches OnCeate().

Comment: Now realized I had an old copy of VS2015 still installed; that, thankfully , has not updated Xamarin automatically (it's ver 4.2). The project still deploys perfectly with this, so I can make some changes, but it's stuck at Android 4.4 and won't let me run the SDK manager. But that's another problem, so maybe a new question for me to post.

Comment: Beginning in August 2018, the Google Play Console will require that new apps target API level 26 (Android 8.0) or higher. Existing apps will be required to target API level 26 or higher beginning in November 2018. normally, if you install the 9.0 SDK platform components, your Target Framework should be setted to android 9.0. If you have solved this issue, please post your solution to answer and mark it, it will help others who have similar issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, no apparent solution for this project under Android 8+ and Xamarin 9. I have a temporary workaround by using VS2015, Xamarin 4 and targeting Android 4.4; this is fine for my own purposes since I won't be trying to use the Google Play Console just yet. 
At some stage (no time available at present) I will start a new 'hello world' project targeting Android 9, and gradually bring in my old code to see when/where it fails.

[later]

Well I had to cancel my holiday because of Coronavirus so I had soem time to do this. Started a new project (Android 8.1, VS2017), imported all the old code. I had to redefine some of the resources but everything now working (in the emulator at least, not tried on a device yet). So maybe this was just an annoying side effect of jumping too many Xamarin versions at once.

Comment: Thanks for your sharing, please mark your answer, it will help others to save time found the correct answer.